# Bootstrap modal "pages"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, single-page-application

How can I make a "page" viewing experience on a bootstrap modal?

This is the kind of flow used in a lot of mobile apps, but by looking at Bootstrap's components I couldn't figure out how to do this kind of flow or if it even supports it.

Very preferably using only vanilla Bootstrap and little to no javascript.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't have any code to give, just my thoughts. You can open the first modal, on a button click or on page load, using JavaScript. Then, when the user clicks on the `To Second Page` button or link, run a JavaScript function that hides the first modal window, and opens the second. Following https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#via-javascript will give you a good understanding of how little JavaScript will be used. As far as achieving what you're looking for without JavaScript, and just html, I don't think that's possible. Hope this helps.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I do this quite a lot but I'm afraid that you'll probably have to use JavaScript.

In the Modal you will initially show just the first 'page' and have some hidden divs that contains your additional 'pages'.

Put a 'hidden' class on the additional pages to begin with that sets them to display:none.

When the user clicks on 'To second page' you hide the currently displayed div by adding the 'hidden' class to it. Then you remove the 'hidden' class from the div/page you want to display thus making it visible.

Your HTML structure:

```
<div class="page-one">
Page One
</div>

<div class="page-two hidden">
Page Two
</div>
```

Then maybe some jQuery like this for each button:

```
$(".btn-show-page-two").on( "click", function() {
        $(".page-one").addClass("hidden");
        $(".page-two").removeClass("hidden");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I did a bootstrap-ish javascript solution to use this using html only if you're interested : http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/1Luvwar5/3/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a little javascript/css snippet to make this easier to do using only html.

Snippet :

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    if(evt.target.matches('.paginator-button')){
    const target = evt.target;
    const href = target.getAttribute("href");
    const activePage = target.closest('.paginator.paginator-active');
    activePage.classList.remove('paginator-active');
    activePage.parentElement.querySelector(href).classList.add('paginator-active');
  }
});
```

Css :

```
.paginator{
  display : none;
}
.paginator-active{
  display : inherit;
}
```

Example usage :

`.paginator` elements need to be siblings

`.paginator-button` need to be children of `.paginator`

```
<div class="paginator paginator-active" id="pageHome">
  <button class="paginator-button" href="page2">To Page 2</button>
</div>
<div class="paginator paginator-active" id="page2">
  <button class="paginator-button" href="pageHome">To Home</button>
</div>
```

Plain JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/3yzxecv7/7/

JQuery Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/1Luvwar5/3/